# React use img onerror

Tags: javascript, image, reactjs

I create a Image component

```
class Image extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <img src= { this.state.imgUrl } onError ={ this.onError() }/>
    );
  }
  onError(){
      console.log('Image onError');
        this.setState(
      { imgUrl: '../default.png' }
    );
  }
}
```

and use it in my view
but if one Image not found. all Image Component In view onError

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `onError={this.onError()}` with instant function call. It should be either `onError={this.onError.bind(this)}` or `onError={() => this.onError()}`.

Comment: Thanks for edit, @FakeRainBrigand. Now the syntax is correct.

Comment: Both solutions are not 100% desirable as they will create a brand new function in every single render. I would do the binding first (in the constructor) and pass the bound function as onError property.

   `this.onError = this.onError.bind(this);`
   `onError={this.onError}`

Comment: Yes, this is 2,5 year old answer. Things have changed after that :). I'd now recommend using fat arrow function `onError = () => { ... }` and then `onError={this.onError}` is just enough without any extra bindings

Answer (score 17):

Remember, if you want to change the styles of the element and/or change the img source, just do something like this:

```
<img
  src={'original src url goes here'}
  alt="example"
  onError={(e) => {
     e.target.src = '/example/noimage.png' // some replacement image
     e.target.style = 'padding: 8px; margin: 16px' // inline styles in html format
  }}
/>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Glad to help @HashirBaig! :)